# Export data from two tables, but only last record

Tags: mysql

I have a table `user` (reduced for clarity):

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Bob |

Then I have a table `user_goal`:

| id | user_id | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111 |
| 2 | 1 | 333 |
| 3 | 1 | 222 |
| 4 | 2 | 120 |
| 5 | 2 | 190 |

I need combine data from those two tables and make an export for all users. I need to have a query that will provide me the following results:

| name | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | 222 |
| Bob | 190 |

Please note that weight should be the last entered one.

I have made this query:

```
select u.name, ug.weigth
    from user u
        inner join user_goal ug on ug.user_id = u.id
    group by ug.user_id
```

but the problem with it, is that it return the first entry in the user_goal. So it returns this:

| name | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | 111 |
| Bob | 120 |

But it should return this:

| name | weight |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | 222 |
| Bob | 190 |

What do I need to change in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next query:

```
select 
  u.name, 
  ug.weight 
from users u 
inner join user_goal ug on ug.user_id = u.id
inner join (
    select max(id) last_id from user_goal group by user_id
) last_value on last_value.last_id = ug.id;
```

[Test SQL online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=0cb57defdae452f90b317e9c1ad70bd3&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

In case MySQL 8.0 you can use window function row_number() as approach:

```
select name, weight from (
  select 
    u.name, 
    ug.weight,
    row_number() over (partition by ug.user_id order by ug.id desc) rn
  from users u 
  inner join user_goal ug on ug.user_id = u.id
) t where rn = 1;
```

[SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=e959f999405721f7367f82a50a02d00c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)